# React Native listen to variable changes

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to make an app that will allow me to update a textbox after receiving a change in a variable. However the variable takes a long time to update, and await does not work to wait for my variable to update probably because of the timeout function I used. How do I create a listener or something of that sort to check for any variable changes?

Below is my code snippet

```
const [banana, setBanana] = useState(-1);
  const updateLocation = async() => {
    const majorSig = scheduledScan();
    setBanana(majorSig);
  }

  const scheduledScan = async() => {
  beaconScan();

  // Scans for 20 seconds
  setTimeout( async()=> {
    beaconStop();
    await getAndUpdateUserLoc();
    // console.log("Loggged: ", await getUserLoc());
    // console.log("major: ", await getSignificantMajor());
    currentMajor = await getSignificantMajor();
    return currentMajor;
  }, 20000);
}
```

When I run updateLocation(), my code is supposed to run for 20 second. I want it to wait until it finishes running scheduledScan() and returns a value to majorSig before it runs the setState function. However right now all it does is run scheduledScan() and update setState immediately to a wrong value. What should I do to make it behave in the way I want?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not set the state inside the timeout instead of returning the values?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your async updateLocation function, your await statement is missing. Let's add it appropriately:

```
const updateLocation = async () => {
  const majorSig = await scheduledScan();
  setBanana(majorSig);
};
```

Then, It would be a good idea if you follow a promise approach in your time-limited function by using a `Promise.race` which lets your function either time out or successfully return a value:

```
const scheduledScan = async () => {
  beaconScan();
  return Promise.race([
    async () => {
      beaconStop();
      await getAndUpdateUserLoc();
      // console.log("Loggged: ", await getUserLoc());
      // console.log("major: ", await getSignificantMajor());
      currentMajor = await getSignificantMajor();
      return currentMajor;
    },
    new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Request timed out')), 20000)),
  ]);
};
```